# How to determine if a vertex has odd or even number of outE()?

Tags: gremlin

I wanna get the vertex that has odd number of edges. Something like these:

```
 g.V().where(out().count() % 2 != 0)
```

Of course, `%` can not be used here. Is there a alternative way?

Answer (score 3):

There is no mod operator for sack but there are div, mult and minus.

```
g.withSack(0).V().as('a').where(outE().count().sack(assign).sack(div).by(constant(2)).sack(mult).by(constant(2)).sack(minus).sack().is(0)) // even

g.withSack(0).V().as('a').where(outE().count().sack(assign).sack(div).by(constant(2)).sack(mult).by(constant(2)).sack(minus).sack().is(neq(0))) // odd
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no step for a division and to my knowledge also not for modulo, but you can use a lambda for that:

```
g.V().outE().count().filter{count = it.get(); count % 2 == 1;}
```

(Note that this query requires a scan of the complete graph in most systems as no index is used.)

[This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/E9ZzVojn7CU) in the Gremlin-users group contains more information about mathematical operations with Gremlin.